# Is it possible to bind and listen to one IP address with TCP/IP sockets? (Linux/C)

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, tcp

I have always used:

```
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
```

which means that I will accept connections from any interface. If I replace the INADDR_ANY with “192.168.0.1”. Does this mean I will only accept connections from the IP address of 192.168.0.1, or does it mean I will accept connections from the interface of 192.168.0.1 resides on?

I have a situation now where I have multiple clients (each with a unique IP address but same port number), trying to connect to one server. Can I have multiple listens functions (separate threads) listening to a unique IP address and port? Or do I have to accept any connection and get the network information after I've connected?

---

Edit To give more clarification.

If I say serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.1") and a client with IP address 192.168.0.2 tries to connect, will the listen command reject this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bind address is the local address to listen on; you can specify the address of a local interface.

If you want to control who can connect, you can either inspect the peer address inside the select/accept loop, or limit inbound connections using iptables.

**Update**

> If I say serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.1") and a
>   client with IP address 192.168.0.2 tries to connect, will the listen
>   command reject this? I want to be able to have multiple thread, each
>   servicing a unique IP address.

No, the address is an address on a local machine. Given that you're going for a multi-threaded design, I'd recommend you run the listen/accept code in one thread, check the client address, decide what worker thread is appropriate, and then spawn it.

At the risk of showing my age, I still prefer using listen/accept/select for most socket code - it's a personal taste thing, and yes, does influence the design when it comes to blocking/non-blocking IO, buffering, etc.

Comment: Note that IPs are easily spoofable, so the check of the remote IP shouldn't be the only access control measure. It's a nice way to reap out most people with relatively low resource consumption though.

Comment: True, but we're on 192.168.x.y, so it's a private network; security doesn't seem to be the primary concern here.

Comment: Phil: Security should ALWAYS be a concern when speaking plain sockets, esp. when the OP intends to filter certain clients. Often, those services somehow end up on public or at least semi-public networks. And if the service is abused as a proxy for accessing protected servers behind it, things get messy soon...

Comment: That's why I just posted it as a comment for others to consider when implementing something like this. No ofence...

Comment: If I say serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.1") and a client with IP address 192.168.0.2 tries to connect, will the listen command reject this? I want to be able to have multiple thread, each servicing a unique IP address.

Comment: IP addresses are not easily spoofable. Well, I mean they are, you can send what you like. But good luck getting back a response, or establishing a tcp handshake unless you're on the same physical network as the one you  are spoofing.

Answer (score -1):

> If I replace the INADDR_ANY with “192.168.0.1”. Does this mean I will
>   only accept connections from the IP address of 192.168.0.1, or does it
>   mean I will accept connections from the interface of 192.168.0.1
>   resides on?

Yes

> I have a situation now where I have multiple clients (each with a
>   unique IP address but same port number), trying to connect to one
>   server. Can I have multiple listens functions (separate threads)
>   listening to a unique IP address and port? Or do I have to accept any
>   connection and get the network information after I've connected?

Yes. You can "fork" (i.e. create a new thread) for each connection you wish to process, however you'd have to do the filtering yourself. There is no way (that I know off in the API) to offload that work to the stack.